# SharePoint 2013 Export and Bulk delete documents/lists

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-online

Does anyone have any idea on how to do bulk deletes from SharePoint 2013 document lists? I need to delete nearly a million records at once. Using the delete option from the lists itself is very time consuming and can only delete first 100 records at a time. Cleaning up is really hectic.

For document libraries it is easier to open it in explorer view and then you can select the no. of files and delete them easily but if you have setup a view you can only delete first 100 files and then go on next until all have been deleted under that view.

Is there a simpler way to do export and bulk delete or any good tool?

- **export and bulk delete documents from document libraries using views**. Reason for using views is because we only need to export and delete documents based on certain filtered criteria's e.g. date range [Today]-100
- and also to do **bulk delete from lists** containing millions of records.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.processbatchdata.aspx

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19036.sharepoint-using-powershell-to-perform-a-bulk-delete-operation.aspx#Example

That's probably the fastest way to perform bulk deletes in your scenario.